# An @Moderators ping

Tags: feature-request, comments, chat, ping

Recently, I have found several occasions where I could really use an `@Moderators` ping that alerts all **elected** moderators of the site.

Do you agree? Would this be nice? Can we make this happen?

Comment: Why you don't want to use flags?

Comment: Yeah, I think that's what a flag *is* (albeit a less annoying version since it lets them look at the queue rather than being constantly pinged).

Comment: No, I don't agree. It won't be nice and I don't think it will happen.

Comment: If you want to ping *a* moderator, raise a flag. If you want to ping *all* moderators, post a question on the Meta site.

Comment: Can you describe an occasion where you needed to notify *all* moderators site-wide?

Answer (score 43, accepted):

The question that is important here is, do all the moderators want to be pinged by you?

In almost all cases you just need *any* moderator, not *all* moderators. Just use a flag for that, this can be processed by the next available moderator without bothering any of the other moderators without cause.

Chat is also not suitable for all moderation activities, moderators don't necessarily have the time to discuss every single decision in detail. If it's an important issue that needs to be discussed, a meta post is probably the best solution anyway.

And many moderators, like me, are pretty much constantly logged into the main chat room of their sites when they are around, so you can ping them.

Answer (score 36):

We already have this. It's known as a "flag"

[image]

When you flag a question or an answer, you get the ability to enter a message to a moderator:

[image: flagging dialog with option in need of moderator]

Using flags is **good** because:

1. They are visible only to mods, so they can contain private information
2. They show up in a single, sorted list in the mod tools
3. Mods have a lot of work to do. Having everything in one place is very helpful.
4. It keeps a separation between administrative issues and comment chatter.
5. Flags have a history, so other mods can see what flags were cast on a question, who acted on them, etc.

Comment: What about chat? What if there is nothing wrong with the question, and you are doing it in Meta?

Comment: Doing *what?* You can flag on Meta. Mods get notifications of *every meta question* in their inbox. And for chat, just chat away and anyone who wants to join in will do so...

Comment: *What if there is nothing wrong with the question* I guess my question is, **when would you need to ping all moderators if there isn't a problem?**