# Is there a way to appropriately nudge a moderator to handle my old flags, or is waiting the only option?

Tags: discussion, flags, moderation, moderators

**Moderators are hard working volunteers**, this we can all agree. The moderators on many Stack Exchange networks, including this one, are also very efficient.

**But on other smaller sites**, even the simplest *No longer needed* flags **can take up to months** to be handled. This isn't much of a problem for me, but when flagging other more derogatory content, I tend to feel more uneasy at the long wait.

For one specific site, it does not seem to be the case where the moderators are all inactive, as there are still moderators answering questions frequently and in chat, pretty much daily.

I have, on one or two occasions, pinged a mod *(from a smaller site)* in chat to handle my custom flags **on some comments that caused more damage the longer they stayed** *(as long as the question commented on wasn't buried too deep)*, and they kindly took action, but pinging them doesn't seem right.

Quoting https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/126990/773001:

> Chat is also not suitable for all moderation activities, moderators don't necessarily have the time to discuss every single decision in detail.

Again, this does not seem to be a problem whatsoever on the larger sites *(kudos to the moderators there as well as here)*, but it's several smaller sites I know that are in question.

Long question short, **is there any way to appropriately nudge/ask a moderator to handle flags** *(that have been sitting for months)*, or is waiting the only option?

Comment: Are you using the appropriate flags? "No longer needed" is the wrong flag to use for a comment that needs to be removed sooner rather than later. If rude/abusive flags are taking months to resolve, that should be escalated to the CM team.

Comment: Also note, that "no longer needed" are flags that the community can resolve by a certain number of users flagging a comment the same way, similar to spam flags. They also age away after 4 days, so that could be why you don't see them get handled. https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/17364/how-does-comment-voting-and-flagging-work/17365#17365

Comment: @ColleenV "If rude/abusive flags are taking months to resolve, that should be escalated to the CM team." Should yes, but is it? And would it be a guarantee for a successful handling? Maybe more moderators would be a good idea in such a situation, if it occurs regularly.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

Waiting is your only option.  Moderators are volunteers with their time, and their time may be taken up on other things.

To be honest if it's a persistent thing that there's a distinct and acute lack of moderation that only a diamond mod can handle, perhaps it'd be a good time for a Community Manager to get involved.

Comment: ... in which case, you can always use the Contact Us form.

Comment: If there are three *active* moderators but no one handles  *several flags* for days or weeks on end then something is seriously broken. If there's only one active moderator, when the minimum number is three (me guessing), then something is still seriously wrong, tasks cannot fall on the shoulders of a single volunteer. Yes, moderators are volunteers but that doesn't mean they can go AWOL for weeks on end, or just hang out on chat. The OP should also post on the site's meta and see how much time lapses before receiving a response. More than a month, then is the time to use the Contact form.

Answer (score -2):

Mods could be active but still overworked. In that case more mods would be a good solution. To see if they are overworked (which isn't their fault, they are volunteers), a statistic should be made public about how many flags remain unhandled for how long. That would give a better basis for estimation where the problem really is.

If the mods were not overworked but still some flags did not get handled, it means they effectively got declined. If they got declined you can still discuss the matter on the respective meta and try to reach consensus.

If my flag wasn't handled one way or another within a reasonable time and if I felt strongly about this (i.e. see strong disadvantages if the flag remains unhandled) I would open a meta post about a possible general delay in handling flags (avoid making it about personal flags) suggesting that maybe mods are overworked and more of them are needed or that mods are unable to come to a conclusion by themselves and need meta to reach consensus.

I wouldn't ping a mod though, because if we would all do it like this in case our flags do not get handled, that would annoy mods quite a lot without reducing the workload. A queue and some public information about it (like how many flags are older than X days) should be enough.

Comment: And if you really, **really** feel the urge to inform (do so at your own risk) about a possible backlog in flags, make sure you make it a general question, and not something about *your* flag(s).

Comment: I would assume your 6-8 weeks estimate would be appropriate for a site like Stack Overflow, but I would find such a turn around for mod flags totally outrageous for smaller sites.

Comment: @ThomasMarkov Not sure how exactly you find it totally outrageous for smaller sites? Should mod flags be handled faster or slower on smaller sites in your opinion? What do you think would be an acceptable time range for smaller sites? I'm not sure I do understand why there should be a dependence on the size of the site. Yes StackOverflow is larger, but also has more mods. Mod flags should approximately be handled within the same time everywhere on the network because they are all equally important. One would target approximately the same ratio of mods to mod flags everywhere.

Comment: @Trilarion Stack overflow has wayyyyyyy more questions that [politics.se] (using that as an example since it's my main site), but so my moderator flags are nearly always handled in a day (or occasionally, two).

Comment: @EkadhSingh-ReinstateMonica As I said, SO has more mods but also more questions. If the ratio of mods to questions is the same however, I would not expect an effect on average handling of mod flags.  You say " wayyyyyyyyy more questions ... so flags are nearly always handled in a day..". Why does the first imply the second? The more questions, the faster the expected handling?

Comment: @Trilarion oops, that was a typo. I meant my flags are handled in a day on politics, not SO.

Comment: @EkadhSingh-ReinstateMonica Okay, but I still do not understand the size argument. Where does the size of the exchange influence how quick mod flags are handled on average? Maybe on smaller exchanges with smaller numbers of mods and flags, extremes happen more often and so the variance in flag handling is larger. In light of the general experience here that flag handling takes days, I removed the 6-8 weeks and just leave it at a "reasonable time".